# Issue with error handling with asyncio.timeout on Discord.py

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py

I am new to Discord Python, and I wanted to tackle error handling. I came across an issue related to wait_for() where for some reason, on_command_error can not catch asyncio.timeout error.

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="--", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx:commands.Context, error):
    print(f"{error} in command: {ctx.invoked_with}")
    if isinstance(error, asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError):
        print('aaaa')
    if isinstance(error, asyncio.TimeoutError):
        print('bbbb')
    else:
       raise error

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == ctx.channel
    await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=3, check=check)

bot.run("token")
```

Here are the error code it spat out:

```
  File "C:\Users\xstri\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:/Python/Python Project/main.py", line 22, in test
    await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=3, check=check)
  File "C:\Users\xstri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 501, in wait_for
    raise exceptions.TimeoutError()
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xstri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:/Python/Python Project/main.py", line 16, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\xstri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1349, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\xstri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\xstri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TimeoutError:
```

Could anyone explain why? If so, how can you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error from `on_command_error(ctx:commands.Context, error):` is a [`commands.CommandError`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.ext.commands.CommandError) exception.

Despite your error being an `asyncio.TimeoutError` exception at the beginning, it is transformed into a `commands.CommandError` instance so it can be caught and handled in the [`on_command_error()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_command_error) event handler.

As `asyncio.TimeoutError` (or `asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError`) are never instances of `commands.CommandError`, you won't be able to catch the exception inside the `on_command_error()` event handler with that code.

If you don't know which type of instance of `commands.CommandError` you need to handle, you can check it using the [`with_traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.with_traceback) method

---

Note: `commands.CommandError` inherits from `discord.DiscordException` which inherits from the python `Exception` class, which is a [BaseException](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException) subclass:

---

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx : commands.Context, error : commands.CommandError):
    print(error.with_traceback)
    # Print result:
    # <built-in method with_traceback of CommandInvokeError object at 0x00...>

    # ...
```

In your case, what you need to handle is a `CommandInvokeError` instance:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx : commands.Context, error : commands.CommandError):
    # print(error.with_traceback)
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        print('error caught in "on_command_error": "isinstance"')
        # ...
    else:
       print('error not caught')
```

---

---

If you have more than one command that ends up raising a `CommandInvokeError` exception and you want a specific error-handling for each one, you will need to either add a `try-except` inside of the command (first chunk of code below) or, in the `on_command_error()`
event handler, create a specific handling for each command (second chunk of code below):

```
@bot.command(name='test')
async def test(ctx):
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == ctx.channel
    try:
        await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=3, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('error caught in "try-except"')
        # ...
```

or

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx : commands.Context, error : commands.CommandError):
    # print(error.with_traceback)
    if ctx.command.name == "test":
        print('error caught in "on_command_error": "command.name=test"')
        # ...
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        print('error caught in "on_command_error": "isinstance"')
        # ...
    else:
       print('error not caught')
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! Thought I would never get a reply. That with_traceback tip is going to be super helpful. That makes sense as to why `on_command_error()` can not catch `asyncio.TimeoutError`.

Do you think it is a good idea to make a completely new empty error class inheriting from `commands.CommandError` when trying out the `try-except` such as this? This was my current work-around while I was waiting for a response.
```try:
    await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=3, check=check)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    raise CustomTimeoutError```

Comment: @Akyer If your plan is to have more than one command that may raise an `asyncio.TimeoutError`, and you want all of those commands to behave in the same way (which is a behave that doesn't make sense for other exceptions that end up producing a `commands.CommandInvokeError`), then it looks to me as the best way to approach the problem